# Android Eclipse DDMS Update Heap Button Disabled

Tags: android, eclipse, profiling, heap-memory, ddms

I am trying to profile memory usage of my Android application using DDMS. When I start the tool with my device connected, the device shows up. However, the button/tab for "Update Heap" is greyed out (disabled). Any idea why?
[image]

Comment: ["In the Devices tab, select the **process** that you want to see the heap information for."](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#heap)

Comment: I don't see any process there. Clicking on the device does not show up anything.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid enough - I was trying using the release build. Loaded the debug build from Eclipse and the options were enabled.